# wireless network adapter supported on ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, 15.04, hp-pavilion, ralink

I would like to know if my [network adapter](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uyhhds7athjvnr2/Screenshot%20%281%29.png?dl=0) is in anyway compatible with Ubuntu.

Dual booting Ubuntu 15.04 with windows 8.1 on an HP Pavilion G6 1d98dx.

I've tried so many different distros but the problem is the same on all of them "wireless disabled by hardware switch" I've tried `rfkill unblock all` but that did not fix the problem.

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:b293 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05dc:a20b Lexar Media, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek [Radeon HD 6520G]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] BeaverCreek HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6500D and 6400G-6600G series]
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h Processor Root Port
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [IDE mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 13)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:15.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
00:15.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 0 (rev 43)
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 6
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 5
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 12h/14h Processor Function 7
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsusb&&lspci`? Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question  so everyone can see what exact hardware you have. (No dropbox here and definitely no cookies...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your terminal-output and dropbox-picture the chipset of your WIFI-adapter is a **Ralink RT5390** and they [open sourced this driver some years ago](http://phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTA5MA)...!
according to [this old tutorial](https://atinfinity.wordpress.com/2011/05/21/ralink-rt5390-wi-fi-driver-on-ubuntu-11-04/) it should work with every Linux Kernel above 3.x (this means Ubuntu 11.10) out of the box.

**BUT** as you can see in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138302) there occur some problems...

---

1. please check first if you really don't have turned off WIFI by a hardware switch!?! - or accidentally disabled the WIFI by software via rightclicking on the network-monitor or something...?
2. consider to try out (via live medium) the current LTS (14.04 --> maybe it will be easier to maintain your system because 15.04 will be supported just until january 2016 and the 14.04 LTS until April 2019).
3. however... if it remains not working [there should be a solution](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2138302&page=5&p=13056330#post13056330):
   just execute the steps on [this page](https://github.com/agerwick/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver) (a other network connection is required) and it should work... this solution is tested with 14.04 LTS but maybe it could also work with 15.04.

Comment: tried the 3rd suggestion you metioned but now instead of it saying disabled by hardware switch it has enable networking checked conection information and edit connections