# Does Ubuntu work with 802.1 x EAP Wifi?

Tags: networking, 16.04

so I am thinking of upgrading my laptop from windows 10 to Ubuntu, I have used it in the past and loved it, but never thought to install it on my new laptop. I use this laptop for school however, and the wifi there is encrypted with 802.1 x EAP security. Would I be able to connect and use the internet there?

also, something interesting, when I try to connect my phone to it (I747, CM12) using my account the school provided, it'll connect, but it wont load anything when I open chrome because it doesn't prompt me to login. Is this the same for Ubuntu?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: My school uses 802.11x EAP. I can connect just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The  802.1 x EAP Wifi will work like charm in Ubuntu and no need to worry about it. In case if you face any issues in connecting the try out our own link to fix the same. Ask Ubuntu always there with a fix :-)

[wireless network adapter supported on ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645712/wireless-network-adapter-supported-on-ubuntu)